# How implement a barrier using semaphores

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I have the following problem to solve:

*Consider an application where there are three types of threads: Calculus-A,Calculus-B and Finalization. Whenever a thread type Calculus-A ends, it calls the routine endA(), which returns  immediately. Whenever a thread type Calculus-B ends, it calls the routine endB(), which returns immediately. Threads like Finalization routine call wait(),
which returns only if they have already completed two Calculation-A threads and 2 Calculation-B threads. In other words, for exactly 2 conclusions of Calculus-A and 2 conclusions of Calculus-B one thread Finalization is allowed to continue.
There is an undetermined number of threads of the 3 types. It is not known the order of the routines called by threads. Threads Completion are answered in the order of arrival.
Implement routines endA(), endB() and wait() using semaphores. Besides the variables initialization, the only possible operations are P and V. Solutions with busy-waiting are not acceptable.*

Here's is my solution:

```
semaphore calcA = 2;
semaphore calcB = 2;
semaphore wait = -3;

void endA()
    {
        P(calcA);
        V(wait);
    }

void endB()
    {
        P(calcB);
        V(wait);
    }

void wait()
    {
        P(wait);
        P(wait);
        P(wait);
        P(wait);
        V(calcA);
        V(calcA);
        V(calcB);
        V(calcB);
    }
```

I believe that there will be a deadlock due to the wait's initialization and if and wait() executes before endA() and endB(). Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need semaphore `wait`? (remember endA and endB must return *immediately*)

Comment: I've created the `semaphore wait` to ensure that the process `wait()` will only execute exactly after 2 threads Calculus-A and 2 threads Calculus-B were executed. Do you believe that the semaphore `wait` and all the instructions related to it may be left away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to view semaphore problems as problems where one must identify "sources of waiting" and define for each a semaphore and a protocol for their access.

With that in mind, the "sources of waiting" are

- Completions of CalcA
- Completions of CalcB
- *Maybe*, if I understood this right, a wait on whole completion groups, consisting of two CalcAs and two CalcBs. I say *maybe* because I'm not sure what *"Threads Completion are answered in the order of arrival."* means.

Completions of CalcA and CalcB should therefore increment their respective counters. At the other end, *one* Finalization thread gains exclusive access to the counters and waits in any order for the needed number of completions to constitute a completion group. It then unlocks access to the next group.

My code is below, although since I'm unfamiliar with the Dutch `V` and `P` I will use `take()`/`give()`.

```
semaphore calcA    = 0;
semaphore calcB    = 0;
semaphore groupSem = 1;

void endA(){
    give(calcA);
}

void endB(){
    give(calcB);
}

void wait(){
    take(groupSem);
    take(calcA);
    take(calcA);
    take(calcB);
    take(calcB);
    give(groupSem);
}
```

The `groupSem` semaphore ensures all-or-nothing: the thread that enters the critical section will get the next two completions of each of CalcA and CalcB. If `groupSem` wasn't there, the first thread to enter `wait` could take two As and block, then be taken over by another thread that grabs two As and two B and then run away.

A worse problem that exists if the `groupSem` isn't there is if this second thread takes two As, one B and then blocks, and then the first thread grabs the second B. If somehow the result of the finalization allows more runs of CalculationA and CalculationB, then you may have a deadlock, because there may be no more opportunity for instances of calculation A and B to complete, therefore leaving the finalization threads hanging, unable to produce more calculation instances.